# label for form input

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I would like to define a custom label for form input:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Question'); ?>

    <?php
    echo $this->Form->input('my_answer', array('label' => 'Select an answer',
            'type' => 'radio', 'options' => array($question['Question']['answer_choice1'], $question['Question']['answer_choice2'], 'value' => ''));

    ?>
```

The form displays 'My Answer', instead of 'Select an answer'.   The form works as expected, if the radio options are removed.   Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

There is not a way to use the standard label option with a radio button, but it is easy to add in your view with the use of a form label function:

How about using `FormHelper::label(string $fieldName, string $text, array $options)` You could define the label class in the options array, so (for example):

```
echo $options = array( /* relevant stuff goes here */ );
echo $attributes = array( /* relevant stuff goes here */ );
echo $this->Form->radio('gender', $options, $attributes);
echo $this->Form->label('gender', 'Text of your label', array('label'=>'radioBtn'))
```

you can also refer detail document for [CakePHP Cookbook on FormHelper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#form-element-specific-methods)